# How to update foreign key value django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

Let say I have following models (models.py）:

```
class stockList(models.Model):
 product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True)
 product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
 product_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 product_description = models.TextField(null=True)
 quantity_in_store = models.IntegerField(null=True)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class stockOut(models.Model):
 staff_name = models.ForeignKey("staff", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
 stock = models.ForeignKey("stockList", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
 shipping_qty = models.IntegerField(null=True)
 shipping_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

First of all I have to do a subtraction between quantity_in_store (from stockList models) and shipping_qty(from stockout models) and to get the final quantity that left in store. However, I have get the final quantity but I would like to update the value of final quantity into the quantity_in_store(from stockList models) How would I go about doing this? Thanks

admin models:

```
class stockout(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ["staff_name", "stock", "shipping_qty", "shipping_company"]

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    stock = obj.stock
    shipping_qty = obj.shipping_qty
    if shipping_qty and stock.quantity_in_store:
        obj.stock.quantity_in_store = stock.quantity_in_store - shipping_qty
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Please do not add your code as images.

Comment: Where is the code for your view?

Answer (score 0):

Although check quantity on save is a bad practice, it should be done on validation, you can use your code:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    stock = obj.stock
    shipping_qty = obj.shipping_qty
    if shipping_qty and stock.quantity_in_store:
        obj.stock.quantity_in_store = stock.quantity_in_store - shipping_qty
        # don't forget to save stock after change quantity
        obj.stock.save()
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```